# Is the translation "Even if you fail, just continue to challenge yourself." correct for 「たとえ失敗したとしても、またチャレンジすればいい。」?

Tags: meaning

> たとえ失敗したとしても、**またチャレンジすればいい**。

> Even if you fail, **just continue** to **challenge yourself**.

1. Where can I find the **yourself** part in the Japanese sentence? Also, where is **just continue** in the sentence?
2. Is the translation even accurate!!?
3. Here's my own translation, correct me if I'm wrong:

> Even if you fail, 1(you should) 2(take the challenge) 3(again)].

> たとえ失敗したとしても、3(また)　2(チャレンジすれ)　1(ばいい)。]

Answer (score 2):

Your translation is fine, and it's clear that you understand the constituent parts, but so is "Even if you fail, just continue to challenge yourself". Translation is as much an art as anything. Word for word translations often sounds clunky and unnatural in the target language. I wouldn't overthink things too much.